# css "!important" not important enough: images colors stay inverted

Tags: html, css, darkmode

I wanted to make a dark theme for a website and used something similar to the code below to invert the colors of everything in `<body>` except for the images.

I can't find out why this code doesn't work as I expected: as you can see, even with the `!important`, the image stays inverted:

```css
body { background-color: grey; }

p { color: white; }

.body {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}
            
img {
    -webkit-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    -moz-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    -o-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    -ms-filter: invert(0%) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png" />
        </div>
        <p>The image above should be white</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I wonder how important `!important` actually is, and what should I do to make the images not be inverted.

Of course I don't want to add a class/id to every image in the website, because even if I assume that that could solve my problem, it wouldn't be that efficient and easy to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Well, it's simple, you have to invert once more!

We have learnt `-1 * -1` = `+1`, just like that  :
`Inversion*Inversion=Normal`!
so set the 0% of image to 100%,

**Tip:** `!important` is not needed to override a rule, that is defined above it, this below rule will automatically override the above one, so you can even remove it.

### Answer code:

```css
body { background-color: grey; }

p { color: white; }

.body {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
            
img {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%) !important;
    -moz-filter: invert(100%) !important;
    -o-filter: invert(100%) !important;
    -ms-filter: invert(100%) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png" />
        </div>
        <p>The image above should be white</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*`!important` is not needed to override a rule, that is deffined above it,this below rule will automatically override above one,so you can remove it even"* Doesn't the `.body` have priority because it is a class?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand the inversion as being definitive aka changing the pixels of the image, I thought that was a modifier that was applied on top of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question is already answered and, as already mentioned, the point is that, written in that way, you have to perform the transformation twice. The point here is that the whole assumption to implement **dark mode** by inverting the colors is wrong.

What you are doing is just **inverting a color**, you are not making a color necessarily "darker".

What if you have a text with this color:

[image]

The inverted color would be:

[image]

That is not something that somebody is expecting from a dark mode. In that case you would add another "exception" to your transform your element back and implement it in a different rule.

My suggestion is to define different version of each element for both light mode and dark mode, it is more work to do, but the result is more clean and, most important, more predictable. Of course, if you prefer you can use a library or study some best practice to implement dark mode too.

Comment: That's a good point, I thought about it a bit, but I essentially have greyscale elements in my website (except images). This was for a school project and the teacher certainly didn't want that much from me. I know you can also visualize the r, g and b elements as a "block" that you "slide" up or down by modifying every element by the same mount until you hit either 0 or 255 for at least one color component. Microsoft Word seems to use that technique for example. This keeps the difference between the color components while darkening/lighting the color.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not about the `!important` tag at all.

Your first `.body` rule set invert on the body tag, which inverts your entire website. This is NOT the same as applying invert to all the elements.

This `.body` rule does not apply invert to each child element, so there is no invert on the image tag, which you can revert with the `img` rule.

What you should do is instead to apply `invert(100%)` to your image. Then you invert your entire webpage except images once. Images then get inverted twice (First because body is inverted, and then by the `inverted(100%)` on `img`). And inverted twice is the same as not inverted.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the invert on a different object. You should invert the same object. Try this:

```css
body { background-color: grey; }

p { color: white; }

.body {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}
            
.body {
    -webkit-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    -moz-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    -o-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    -ms-filter: invert(0%) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png" />
        </div>
        <p>The image above should be white</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

you can add class to the body `light` and add the invert(100%) to it and have a different class `dark` and add the invert(0%) to it and just toggle it.